# How to use Laravel Echo on production server with https

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, laravel-5.3

I'm wondering what's the proper (or any for that matter) way of setting up Laravel Echo on an https production server.  I've had it working on my local vagrant for a little bit now, and now that I've pushed the changes to production I'm unable to get the script to connect to the node server.  Here is what I currently have.

```
var echo = require('laravel-echo-server');

var options = {
    host: 'https://localhost',
    port: '6001',
    sslCertPath: '/etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt',
    sslKeyPath: '/etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key'
};

echo.run(options);
```

And then in javascript

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'https://localhost:6001'
});
```

The above configuration is how I started out, but I've tried many other combinations, including trying to edit the nginx configuration to bypass https all together.  If bypassing https is the method that's required, any advice on how to do this with Laravel Echo would be appreciated since the socket.io threads on this topic that I've been referencing don't seem to do the trick for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem

**First**. You have to configure your nginx vhost with ssl (no websocket connected yet). I use Let's encrypt  ( https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04)

**Second**. You could create a path on your vhost to proxy to your websocket. This way nginx handles ssl protocol and also you do not use another port

```
location /ws/{

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}
```

After that your script will have to connect to `https://localhost/ws/

Note: I use port 3000 for my `laravel-echo-server` intance and not 6001 as stated in the original question

Comment: This is a really interesting approach, love it. I am curious why you have port 3000 in there, when Laravel Echo Server uses port 6001. Also, would you then configure Laravel Echo Server to run WITHOUT https so that it doesn't try to access the certificates it doesn't have read permissions on?

Comment: You are right, in the question it was stated the 6001 port. You should use that port. I use 3000 port, it can be any other unused port.

Comment: i tried to run this ```sudo service nginx restart``` but i get this error  ```nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "proxy_set_hearder" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf:5
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed```

Comment: @IkechukwuKalu : `nginx -t` is for checking nginx  config.

You have a typo `proxy_set_hearder` instead of `proxy_set_header`

Comment: Thanks for answering, but how do i handle it? I'm running apache and nginx together. My apache runs on port 80 and my nginx on port 8080. Do you have any link that you can refer me too to make my polls from  laravel-echo-server stop failing ?

Comment: Please whenever you have the time https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server/issues/420

Comment: My comment was related to nginx config  when you use nginx as a webserver. If  You have  apache as a webserver you need to define a proxy path for apache to forwards to your laravel-echo-server port.

Comment: @IkechukwuKalu in Apache probably it's done like this: https://gist.github.com/mortenege/91ec6fe02dca6f736303a00f8cea2731

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the user237329 response, the laravel echo setting in javascript should be:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.host,
    path: '/ws/socket.io',
});
```

Comment: Thanks! for me all i need is the proper `host` property. I was setting `/socket.io` instead. I didn't have to set the `path` part as I already proxy the default `/socket.io` instead of `/ws/socket.io`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this issue.  When using Forge and Let's Encrypt, Forge will create folders with a unique ID at the start of the month that will contain your SSL keys.  At first when I tried to use these keys, laravel-echo-server said it couldn't find the keys.  In the code within my question above, I'm referencing two other keys that were on my server that I figured were a sym link to this months correct keys, but that turned out not to be the case.  I did need to refer to the files within the unique ID folders.  In order to get it to work, I simply had to run "**sudo** node socket.js".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will come here with the same problems as me.
First, remember to add the untrusted certificate to browser exceptions, because for laravel echo port we have to do it separately. Otherwise you will get only connection refused in console.
Secondly, the current version laravel echo does not accept the protocol in the host option, but in a separate option named 'protocol'.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.